# Use jQueryUI ToolTip on element in TinyMCE

Tags: css, jquery-ui, iframe, tinymce, jquery-ui-tooltip

I would like to apply jQueryUI's tooltip to elements in the TinyMCE editor, however, they do not appear using FF, and are buggy using IE and Chrome.  I've experimented applying jQueryUI's tooltip to elements in an iframe, and get similar results.  My script is below, and a demo is at http://jsbin.com/abEkOnO/1/ (note that the iframe JS had to be disabled as it causes a proxy error using jsbin).  I think the tooltips are being created, however, maybe the CSS is relative to the iframe and not the document.  I've also experimented by creating my own tooltip plugin (http://jsbin.com/AzaKARe/1/), but also get funky results.

How can I use tooltips on elements in the TinyMCE editor?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>IFrame and tooltips</title>

        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

            tinymce.init({'selector': "#tinymce"});

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.tooltip').tooltip();
                $('#click').click(function(){

                    console.log($('#iframeID').contents().find('.tooltip'));
                    $('#iframeID').contents().find('.tooltip').tooltip();

                    $('#tinymce').html('<div class="tooltip" title="Some Div4">Some DIV4</div><div class="tooltip" title="Some Div5">Some DIV5</div><div class="tooltip" title="Some Div6">Some DIV6</div>');
                    var t=tinymce.editors['tinymce'];
                    t.load();
                    console.log($(t.getBody()).find('div.tooltip'));
                    $(t.getBody()).find('div.tooltip').tooltip();
                });

            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <button id='click'>Click</button>
    <iframe src="iframe_page1.html" id="iframeID"></iframe>
    <div class="tooltip" title="Some Div1">Some DIV1</div>
    <div class="tooltip" title="Some Div2">Some DIV2</div>
    <div class="tooltip" title="Some Div3">Some DIV3</div>

    <div id="tinymce"></div>

</html>
```

iframe_page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Bind</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            .toolTip {width:100px;}
            .myTooTip {
                z-index:99999;
                border:1px solid #CECECE;
                background:white;
                padding:10px;
                display:none;
                color:black;
            }
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tooltip" title="Some Div7">Some DIV7</div>
        <div class="tooltip" title="Some Div8">Some DIV8</div>
        <div class="tooltip" title="Some Div9">Some DIV9</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: after looking at your JSBin I will ask for more details, Please provide the problem details related to toolTip, what exactly is not working and in which browser..

Comment: @MarmiK.  Sorry for the delay, been out of town for a couple of days without Internet access.  Using FF, the tool tip doesn't appear and nor does the default browser display of the title upon hover.  For IE and Chrome, the title of the hovered element gets inserted in the DOM and isn't later removed.  Did you look at my JSBin and if so what did you see?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your case the `e.pageY` was problem,

as tinymce creates a iframe, the `e.pageY` is set to 0 from current location(of tinymce),
So the tool tip again goes to Y=respective to mce position. You need to handle it manually,

I have updated the [`JSbin`](http://jsbin.com/AzaKARe/5/edit) with some tweaks,

this will solve the issue,

although you have to do some small tweaks, for 100% accuracy

Edit : Updated JSBin with JQuery UI,

Undated Link of [`JSBin`](http://jsbin.com/abEkOnO/15/edit)

This works fine without any problem on my side, the problem was we were calling the same function twice and in iframe the mouseOut event is not passed to its parent window, that's why tooltip generated was not getting closed.

I have changing codes and this is simple tooltip that works same as in the iframe above. in example.

I have just removed redundant instance of the tooltip by changing class name :)

I hope this will do finally

Comment: Hi MarmiK,  I see you modified the tooltip plugin that I wrote and not the jQueryUI tooltip.  Note that it still is buggy (tooltip appears two places at once).  I also wanted to just use the jQueryUI tooltip and not mine.  Thanks

Comment: Yes its buggy, I know it shows, I have provided you the way, you have to do the rest, I have pointed the problem. It should not have any other problem not, the work around is there if you insert different class for tip under `tinymce` that will make it perfect, its calling the script twice in my case.

Comment: Thanks MarmiK,  Can this solution be applied to the jQueryUI ToolTip?

Comment: Upon further review, updated answer does not work.  As you indicated, you just changed the class of the targeted elements, but then never selected them with jQueryUI's tooltip, thus the appearance is based of the default browser, and not jQuery.